# Why doesn't my ORMLite custom persister work on Android?

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I wrote a custom persister for the `LocalTime` class from Joda Time:

```
public class LocalTimePersister extends BaseDataType {

    private static final LocalTimePersister instance = new LocalTimePersister();

    private LocalTimePersister() {
        super(SqlType.LONG, new Class<?>[] { LocalTime.class });
    }

    public static LocalTimePersister getSingleton() {
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public Object javaToSqlArg(FieldType fieldType, Object javaObject) {
        if (javaObject == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return ((LocalTime) javaObject).millisOfDay();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object resultToSqlArg(FieldType fieldType, DatabaseResults results, int columnPos) throws SQLException {
        return results.getLong(columnPos);
    }

    @Override
    public Object parseDefaultString(FieldType fieldType, String defaultStr) throws SQLException {
        return Long.parseLong(defaultStr);
    }

    @Override
    public Object sqlArgToJava(FieldType fieldType, Object sqlArg, int columnPos) throws SQLException {
        Long millis = (Long)sqlArg;
        if (millis == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return LocalTime.fromMillisOfDay(millis);
        }
    }
}
```

The class that has a `LocalTime` member has it declared like this:

```
@DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, persisterClass = LocalTimePersister.class)
private LocalTime time;
```

And I have regenerated my database config file:

```
# --field-start--
fieldName=time
canBeNull=false
persisterClass=com.myapp.db.persisters.LocalTimePersister
# --field-end--
```

When I try to create an object that has a `LocalTime` field and add it to the DB, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.joda.time.LocalTime$Property cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
        at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidDatabaseConnection.bindArgs(AndroidDatabaseConnection.java:345)
        at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidDatabaseConnection.insert(AndroidDatabaseConnection.java:156)
        at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.MappedCreate.insert(MappedCreate.java:91)
        at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.create(StatementExecutor.java:450)
        at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.create(BaseDaoImpl.java:310)
        at com.myapp.db.DBHandler.populateDB(DBHandler.java:178)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh gosh, I'm dumb. The answer was hiding right there in the exception:

```
org.joda.time.LocalTime$Property cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
```

In the `javaToSqlArg` method I'm returning

```
((LocalTime) javaObject).millisOfDay()
```

when I should be returning

```
((LocalTime) javaObject).getMillisOfDay()
```

`millisOfDay()` returns a `LocalTime.Property`, `getMillisOfDay()` returns an `int`.